# What is the key differences between bitcoin-qt, bitcoin-cli, bitcoind, bitcoin rpc, and daemon?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, daemon, bitcoincore-gui

Can someone please give a brief explanation on these? I'm getting very confused with the differences, and every tutorial article I read uses these terms interchangeably (I'm trying to set up a pruned node...)

- bitcoin-qt
- bitcoin-cli
- bitcoind
- bitcoin-rpc
- daemon

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of those things are part of the same program, Bitcoin Core.

`bitcoin-qt`: The GUI version of Bitcoin Core. Most users will use this as it provides a nice Graphical User Interface that uses the Qt framework. It does all of Bitcoin Core's functionality, including being a full node and handling your private keys and transactions.

`bitcoind`: The Bitcoin daemon. It is the version of Bitcoin Core which can run in the background. It still does all of the full node and wallet things that `bitcoin-qt` does but is harder to access. `bitcoind` is primarily used for machines without a GUI (e.g. headless server). It can be accessed and interacted with using the JSON-RPC protocol.

`bitcoin-cli`: A tool that you can use to interact with `bitcoind`. It speaks the JSON-RPC protocol that `bitcoind` uses and lets you send commands to `bitcoind` and get the results back.

`bitcoin-rpc`: The Bitcoin Core RPC server. This is part of `bitcoind` and `bitcoin-qt` (it must be set explicitly to be enabled in `bitcoin-qt`). This is the interface that `bitcoin-cli` interacts with.

`daemon`: A daemon is any service which runs in the background. `bitcoind` is a daemon, and so are many other software which run in the background and have no GUI.

Comment: Nice descriptions, thank you this clears stuff up.

Answer (score 3):

All belongs to same application (bitcoin-core) You can download it from bitcoin.org

**bitcoin-qt**
Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework for developers using C++. It's is used for UI in Bitcoin-Qt. See http://qt-project.org/.

**bitcoin-cli**

cli: Command line interface

**bitcoind**

Bitcoind is a headless daemon, and also bundles a testing tool for the same daemon. It provides a JSON-RPC interface, allowing it to be controlled locally or remotely which makes it useful for integration with other software or in larger payment systems

**bitcoin-rpc**

Remote Procedure Call (RPC) is a protocol that one program can use to request a service from a program located in another computer on a network without having to understand the network's details. A procedure call is also sometimes known as a function call or a subroutine call.

**daemon**
Running Bitcoin in background mode (daemon mode)